# Java Issue with Runtime Process Execution: Return 1 Always

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I am having an issue running a command line string in Java. My code is below. When I extract the exact string I am running and paste it into the terminal it works perfectly. Am I missing something? I've condensed my code into this basic example, but the issue is the same.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestCommandLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = null;
        try {
            pr = rt.exec("/Users/comp/Desktop/executable /Users/comp/Desktop/115.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(pr.waitFor());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think this should work? Have you dumped the error stream of the process to see what the error cause was?

Comment: @Pillar Because the command works in the terminal.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.